# Не работает API Яндекс Расписаний

Tags: php

В описании по АПИ расписаний указано, что нужно указывать пункт отправления и назначения в кодах, среди которых есть IATA
Согласно этому я указываю:
Калининград: KGD
Москва: UUMK
И получаю такой запрос
https://api.rasp.yandex.net/v3.0/search/?apikey=
<мой_ключ>&format=json&from=KGD&to=UMMK&lang=ru_RU&page=1&date=2023-11-06&transport_types=plane
Но получаю ошибку
"Не нашли объект по yandex коду KGD"
Что я делаю не так, подскажите пожалуйста. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что вы не указали, в какой системе кодирования передаёте коды:

https://yandex.ru/dev/rasp/doc/ru/reference/schedule-point-point

Надо добавить необязательный GET параметр `system=iata`, потому что по умолчанию API ожидает коды в формате яндекса.

Comment: Спасибо большое, попробую сегодня

Comment: Да, все получилось, благодарю!